# In IE8, $.parseJSON is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

This is the strangest bug I've encountered.

I submit an ajax POST that would retrieve some data.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: data,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data)
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}
)
```

In other version of IE and Chrome, the code would work fine and give the value of `data` which is `{"success": true}`.

But in IE8, `data` would return `undefined` . However, if I do `JSON.stringify(data)` , it would return `{"success":true}`.

I tried to convert the returned string to object via `$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data)` but it returned `undefined` again.

What can I do to get the response data as an object like I would normally in other browser?

EDIT:!! Found the solution. Apparently, the IE8 emulation of IE11 is a total crap and cannot display data correctly. Using IE8 on a virtual machine would correctly display the data and I figured out why it was undefined. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Set `dataType: 'json'`, in case the mimetype isn't correctly set in the response header. Also, you're missing a `{`

Comment: Is this in actual IE8, or in a newer version in IE8 mode, as `console` doesn't seem like a good idea in IE8, it only works with the console open ?

Comment: IE11 using IE8 mode, and in my real code I actually use dataType and contentType appropriately

Comment: What jQuery version do you use?

Comment: Check the error callback. That's probably where you're ending up in IE8. And as I said above; you're still missing a `{`

Comment: `{success: true}` isn't json, therefor your contentType is incorrect for the type of data you are sending. Or, were you referring to the data in the success callback.

Comment: Unfortunately, error callback is not being called. The ajax POST was delivered successfully. I checked the network and the response body is there. It's just somehow the data decides to render itself undefined in the success callback

Comment: And my bad, I format the JSON incorrectly in the question

Comment: don't use `$.parseJSON` with `dataType: "json"`, `data` will already be parsed to a js object.

Comment: Kevin B, I didn't want to use $.parseJSON, but the data returned from the success callback gives me undefined like I said in the question. But when I strigify the undefined data, it gave me an stringified version of the object {"success": true}

Comment: `console.log(data)` giving you undefined, and `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` giving you json makes no sense. I think you're missing a piece of information there.

Comment: Most likely what you mean is `data.success` is undefined. That would indicate to me that `data` isn't what you think it is in IE8, at which point the next step would be to do `console.log(data)` to see what it really is.

Comment: Exactly, Kevin B. I wish I am making this up.

                `success: function (e) {
                    var a = JSON.stringify(e);
                    console.log(e); //returns undefined;
                    console.log(a); //returns {"success":true};
                },`

Comment: And what does console.log(a.success) give you? `e` being undefined makes absolutely no sense. that isn't possible. `JSON.stringify(undefined);` does not produce `{"success":true}`

Comment: Hence, this is the weirdest shit I've ever seen. console.log(a.success) gives me undefined, which make sense because a becomes a string after stringified. Is there any chance that there's some sort of data encoding that makes the data undefined but through strigify it decrypt it ?

Comment: Nope, not that i'm aware of.

Comment: This is very useful info — IE8 emulation has always been very weird. Please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted for future reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! Apparently, the IE8 emulation of IE11 is a total crap and cannot display data correctly. Using IE8 on a virtual machine would correctly display the data and I figured out why it was undefined. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need to do that in IE8. Here is some code that I use with success in IE8 on a website that is live that is using jQuery 1.10.2:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://example.com/service/url',
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 10000
})
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(data.success);
}) 
.fail(function( data ) {
    console.log("Rejected");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Hopefully this example is helpful for you to see how to handle the jQuery callback. The object that comes back is already an object if the result is actually valid JSON.

---

Updated this to be more generic of an answer.

Comment: This has quite a lot of rows that OP surely won't need. `self` for instance.

Comment: Updated this to be more generic of an answer.